# How to include external library into unit tests::Angular2-CLI

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm writing test cases for my project. But unfortunately, after starting the tests by typing `ng test`, I'm receiving following error:

```
Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Plotly is
ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined
```

`Plotly` is an external, chart library. I've tried to declare it inside the `test` file:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { WatchlistComponent } from './watchlist.component';
declare let Plotly: any;

describe('SystemComponent', () => {
  let component: WatchlistComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WatchlistComponent>;
  let element;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ WatchlistComponent ],
      imports: [ FormsModule, MaterialModule ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WatchlistComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should return a positive number', () => {
    expect(component.getScreenHeight()).toMatch(/\d+/);
  });

});
```

Unfortunately, it still doesn't see the `Plotly` and returns error. The first test case for `getScreenHeight()` function is not even being started.

Maybe jasmine is starting the tests even before it was uploaded?

**Edit**:
I'm importing `Plotly` by including `<script src='plotly.js'></script>` in my `index.html` file. `Plotly` is stored locally in the same folder as `index.html` is.

Comment: You're not importing Plotly in your test. You should have a line that says something like `import * as Plotly from 'plotly';`. Just like you should have the same line in the files of your Angular app where you're using Plotly. Unless........... you're including Plotly with a `<script>` tag in `index.html` and using it a global variable. But in this case, it's not just the test that's wrong, it's the way you're using the 3rd-party library.

Comment: Don't upvote every answer, that gives other readers no information about what's useful; upvote *good* ones.

Comment: @AngularFrance Check my edited question. Should I change the way I'm importing the library then?

Comment: @Natalia. That's exactly what I'm saying. :) You should import 3rd party libraries with an `import` statement. But be careful: depending on which module loader you're using (SystemJS, webpack...) you might have to adjust your configuration for the import to work.

Comment: @AngularFrance I'm using webpack. Should I download `Plotly` from npm then?

Comment: Yes! With webpack your job is easier, since it can automatically find the path of npm packages. It means that once you have installed Plotly from npm you can *probably* just write `import * as Plotly from 'plotly'` in your Angular/tests code and it should work.

Comment: @AngularFrance Using `import * as Plotly from 'plotly'` returns error. "Cannot find module 'plotly'".

Comment: Well, I've never used Plotly with Angular myself. I just pointed out to Natalia that it is NOT good practice to import a 3rd-party lib — any lib, not just Plotly — with a `<script>` tag and then use a global var to access it. A quick Google search turned up some [interesting](https://community.plot.ly/t/cannot-package-plotly-js-via-webpack-in-angular2/2542) [contributions](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/955) about setting up Plotly with Angular 2+...

Answer (score 7):

Load **plotly.js** (*with appropriate path*) file into Karma testing env by adding files config in karma.config.js as below:

karma.config.js

```
config.set({
   ..
   files: ['plotly.js']
   ..
});
```